# How to show only one button based on Status value

Tags: c#, wpf

Having two buttons in datatemplate, only one button can show per row, so for example if `Stuaus` value is 1 then show button1, else show button2

Note: Status value is coming from database.

I am using WPF datagrid:

Current code show both and I don not know how to show and hide button based on Status value.
`Updated Code`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fungsi" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Button Name="btn1" Content="Test1" Background="#FFCC00 "></Button>
     <Button Name="btn2" Content="Test2" Background="Blue"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you add the converter to the resources and bind the status to visibility of the the button..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a converter and tackle with the converter parameter. Refer below code. Agree @Sam, but if he has more status then below code will help.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid_Status.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGrid_Status"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window4" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:StatusConverter x:Key="StatusConverter"></local:StatusConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fungsi" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Name="btn1" Content="Success" Background="Green"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter},ConverterParameter=a}"></Button>
                            <Button Name="btn2" Content="InProg" Background="Yellow"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter},ConverterParameter=b}"></Button>
                            <Button Name="btn3" Content="Failed" Background="Red"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter},ConverterParameter=c}"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DataGrid_Status
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window4.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window4 : Window
    {
        public Window4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyClass obj = new MyClass();
                obj.Name = "Name" + i;
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    obj.Status=StatusEnum.Success;
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    obj.Status = StatusEnum.Failed;
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.Status = StatusEnum.InProgress;
                }
                lst.Add(obj);
            }
            DataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
        }
    }

    class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            StatusEnum status = (StatusEnum)value;
            string param = parameter as string;
            if ((status == StatusEnum.Success && param == "a")|| (status == StatusEnum.InProgress && param == "b")|| (status == StatusEnum.Failed && param == "c"))
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    }

    enum StatusEnum
    {
        Success,
        Failed,
        InProgress
    }
}
```

Comment: it says the name `StatusConverter` does not exist in the namespace?

Comment: You need to add the namespace in the xaml.

Comment: Updated my answer.. look for the namespace on the top of the window.xaml

Comment: I updated my code, I am not sure why it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Have the `Button`s `Visible` state bound to a bool you update in the code behind i.e.:

```
<Button Name="btn1" Content="Test1" Background="#FFCC00 " Visible="{Binding btn1Visible}"/>
```

and in the code behind:

```
public bool btn1Visible
{
     get { return _btn1Visible; }
     set
     {
         _btn1Visible = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("btn1Visible");
     }
}
```

where the `NotifyPropertyChanged` is a wrapper around the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` that's part of the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you would have to bind the visibility of the buttons to the state somehow.

i usually use a bool to visibility converter to do this.
this returns a visibility value of visible on true or collapsed if false.

you could use the same or create your own converter based off your state variable.
e.g return true if value == 1 return false if anything else